Staging ground bug: editing post body does not work; edits silently discarded
I saw this post in the staging ground:

https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/78625597

After checking that it wasn't a dupe, I thought it could be a decent
question with some editing improvements, so I:

Clicked the "Edit post" radio button and then "Submit" button.

Edited the question title.

Edited the question body.

Clicked "Approve and post on main site" radio button.

Clicked "Add an upvote when posted on main site" checkbox.

Clicked "Submit" button.

I did not provide an edit summary.  (That was by mistake; I just forgot.)


The question was then published:

Can std::recursive_mutex ever cause a deadlock?

But while the edits to the title took effect, the edits to the question
did not!  The posted question had the original, unedited text.
(I then quickly edited the posted question and attempted to re-create
my edits from memory.)

Note: You can view the edit in the SG if that happens and you can also see it happening by being redirected to the post you just reviewed after approving.
